# Shortcuts at documentation, jobs, review, help etc

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

Why aren't there shortcuts in the documentation, jobs, review and help center of the site? You can navigate the full Q&A, tags and user part with shortcuts except they I've noticed above. Is this a feature to SO or isn't that forgotten to implement?